# netfilter_queue : use --queue-balance in multithreaded environment

Tags: c, linux, kernel

I'm using libnetfilter_queue for userspace modification of
incoming/outgoing packets. I have been using a single threaded model.
But i've found out that from 2.6.31 kernel, its possible to have
different queues for different connection. so i was wandering if its
possible to manage each queues in different threads.

normally i set up the queue handling like bellow:

```
struct nfq_handle * h = nfq_open();
nfq_unbind_pf(h, AF_NET);
nfq_bind_pf(h,m AF_NET);
struct nfq_q_handle(h, 0, &cb, NULL);
nfq_set_mode(qh, NFQNL_COPY_PACKET, 0xffff);
```

now if i want to manage like 100 queues, i will pack h,qh and que_num in
a structure and loop over it to initialize.

now my question is :

if i initialize above in the main thread and want to run the callbacks
in separate threads, is it enough to run the even loop in a function which will
be given to pthread_create()? Will it run the callbacks in threads?

i'm not sure, but my understanding tells me, a packet is popped from the
queues when nfq_set_verdict is returned. so i need to run
nfq_set_verdict in separate threads so that i packets can be popped from
queues parallel.

EDIT: i provide my code if someone needs them to understand my problem. pasting all codes here seems unreasonable as it creates visual noise.

Comment: Is it too slow doing this in a single thread? If not, why are you jumping to throw threads at it? People throw the thread lever far too often without really thinking it through.

Answer (score 2):

I know this is a bit of necroposting, but in case anyone stumbles on this problem.

If you use `--queue-balance` for multithreading and netfilter seems to put all packets in one queue, one should add `--queue-cpu-fanout`, which forces iptables to share packets based on cpuid instead of flow.